# Trim string not working in array when multiple values

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports, dynamic-arrays

I have a Crystal Report with multiple arrays populated by formulas. Within these arrays I need to list the codes which come off of a formula based on a description. I.e. If "Denver" then "DIA" else if "Seattle" then "SEA". There can be multiple records that need complied. When I only have 1 record it works great, [DIA], however if there is more than one value the conversion  [Denver, Seattle]. In my head I know this is because of the if/then situation since both are true. What is a better way to handle this scenario?

I have tried changing the formula to be an OR statement.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update the question to include the code for the formula you are currently using, a description of the output, and a description of how you would like the output.  This would allow us to reproduce the problem and recommend a solution.

Comment: I can't add the actual formula due to the type of data and work. The example I gave is the best I can do. I feel that did give the formulas and the output that I am looking for and what I am getting, but I will write it out here. 

ff_city
If {city}=trim('Denver')
then 'DIA'
else If {city}=trim('Seattle')
then 'SEA'
else {city}

In the report I have city:[@ff_city].

If I only have one record, say Denver, then my array gives me [DIA] which is perfect. 
However if I have more than one record I get [Denver, Seattle]. 
The formula to switch to airport code no longer works.

Comment: I know it is because I am using an if/then/else statement and it can't comprehend more than one record. I am trying to figure out the best way to handle more than one record in the array while being able to change from city to airport code. And no, that isn't the actual data - just an easy example of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
local stringvar Concatanated_Cities := Join(cities_array, ", ");
Concatanated_Cities := Replace(Concatanated_Cities, "Denver", "DIA");
Concatanated_Cities := Replace(Concatanated_Cities, "Seattle", "SEA");
```

Comment: So I did get it to work with as a variable, however the replace function doesn't work if there is more than 1 variable. I read something where it is because it is evaluating it on the new information stored which makes sense, just not something I have figured out how to work around.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are dealing with. Please provide a concrete example. It would help if you show the input, the expression, and the output. It would also help if you show the value in the intermediate Concatanated_Cities variable.